# AzureADB2CDefaults obsolete, how do I replace it?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web

I'm in the process of updating some nuget packages and noticed that `AzureADB2CDefaults` has been made obsolete. I know that `Microsoft.Identity.UI` has incorporated AzureADB2C into it but I'm unsure how to use it whilst still referencing AzureADB2C, the code below is whats causing this warning:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
```

I've tried setting `DefaultScheme` to just a string of "AzureADB2"
I've also tried adding:

```
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"), 
                        Constants.AzureAdB2C, null);
```

but not having much luck.

Is there any way to reference azure active directory with microsoft identity? Any suggestions on how to replace this bit of code would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** that: **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI`**
Nuget package is obsolete and Microsoft advises to use the
**`Microsoft.Identity.Web`** package.

**To resolve the issue**, install the Latest version of `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI`.

In the **`startup.cs`** file replace the below code:

```cs
 services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
```

with

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)  
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureADB2C"));
```

and instead of using `services.AddRazorPages();` replace it with `services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();`

And also make changes in code by referring to this [**blog**](https://contos.io/migrating-azure-ad-b2c-integration-going-from-net-core-3-1-to-net-5-ea9dafc5238b) by Andreas Helland.

After making the changes, the code will execute successfully:

[image]

[image]

For more in detail, **refer** below links:

[Migrating Azure AD B2C integration going from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 by Andreas Helland](https://contos.io/migrating-azure-ad-b2c-integration-going-from-net-core-3-1-to-net-5-ea9dafc5238b?gi=fed18e65bf7f)

[Azureb2c login is not connecting to account controller by killswitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495102/azureb2c-login-is-not-connecting-to-account-controller)