# What are the auth links when switching from AddAzureADB2C to Microsoft.Identity.Web?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web

I have an API that has a simple "sign-in" link on a plain, hand-written HTML page (no razor pages, no asp pages, nothing).  After I sign in, the cookie is stored so I can use the swagger UI to make simple API calls directly.  This is *very* useful for testing and development.

It uses Azure AD-B2C for authentication.

I followed instructions in MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options), and also questions like [AzureADB2CDefaults obsolete, how do I replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75178447/36228) .  In short I replaced this code:

```
.AddAzureADB2C(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AzureADB2COpenID", "AzureADB2CCookie", AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
     StartupValidator.B2cConfiguration.Bind(options);
});
```

with this new code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
           StartupValidator.B2cConfiguration.Bind(options);
});
```

It compiles and runs fine, but my signin link (which, again, is just a plain hard-coded HTML page) points to:

```
<a href='/AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn/AzureADB2C'>Sign-in</a> |
```

Navigating to that link will hit the local server (localhost when you're doing development), and then the middlewhere does the magic of making the 302 redirect to a URL with all the nonce values and all the other bits and bobs populated.

So my question is: **what is the new signin URL using the new setup**?  This is just a plain HTML page used only in development and debugging, so I don't want to pull in all of razor pages or any of that.  Can this be accomplished?

UPDATE Wed May 24 10:39:14 AM EDT 2023:

After the suggestion to start from the default asp .net core webapp template, I have been able to make progress by 1) pulling in `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` and 2) calling `services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();` during setup.  I can then hit `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn` to sign in (the bearer token is also not available).

This isn't really a solution as it adds ALL the razor and UI dependencies, and increases the size of the container significantly.  Is there *any* way to do this without adding all the UI stuff?

Answer (score 1):

when we have an asp.net core MVC application which integrate microsoft identity(create the project using template and choose authentication), we will have sign in button in the right-top of the page.

[image]

Which will have a `_LoginPartial.cshtml` containing `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>`.

So maybe `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn` is what you want.

I have a test in my side, when I hit this request in the browser, it would redirect to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7245/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxx&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=xx&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.15.1.0`. I'm afraid when you want to use it, you might to have correct variable configuration for `client-id, redirect-url and so on`.

What I have in program.cs and appsettings.json is

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)

"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
```

Comment: `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn` does not work.  I assume it has to do with the fact that this is an azure AD-B2C configuration, not a plain AD config.

Comment: I found the [sample here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L24) which also using `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn`. But the appsettings and the startup code are different, could you pls check the sample?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am correct in saying that this is not possible without
pulling in the UI class and the razor dependencies.  If there's
another simpler solution, I haven't found it.

Here's what I ended up doing (using some simplified diffs):

1. remove AzureADB2C:

```
--- a/Project.csproj
+++ b/Project.csproj
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.0" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI" Version="6.0.6" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.11.0" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.11.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.4" />
     <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.4" />
     <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.3.1" />
```

2. update startup

Part of the whole point of this exercise was to get rid of this
ugly pragma that suppressed the warning about `AddAzureADB2C` being
obsolete.  I can now do that:

```
--- a/Startup.cs
+++ b/Startup.cs
                  
-#pragma warning disable CS0618
```

Replace the auth schema code:

```
                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         }
                     };
-                    })
-                    .AddAzureADB2C(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AzureADB2COpenID", "AzureADB2CCookie", AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
-                    {
-                        StartupValidator.B2cConfiguration.Bind(options);
                 });
 
+                services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
+                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
+                        StartupValidator.B2cConfiguration.Bind(options);
+                        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => {
+                            StartupValidator.BearerTokenDisplay = context.SecurityToken.RawData;
+                            await Task.CompletedTask;
+                        };
+                    })
+                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
+                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
+
                 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                 {
-                    var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
+                    var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                     policyBuilder = policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                     options.DefaultPolicy = policyBuilder.Build();
                 });
             }
```

The key here is the hook into `OnTokenValidated`.  Before, I was using
a claims reader extension to intercept the call on the postback to the signin
link.  The original code called the `b2clogin.com` url with a query parameter
of `response_type=id_token`.  This does not appear to be available anymore (it
always uses `response_type=code`), so I can't grab the auth token on the
post-back.

Absolutely none of the Microsoft documentation on how to get the token
after authentication worked
(e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore)),
and this was a very frustrating part of the process.  Eventually I
discovered that you can hook into the flow after the token has been validated,
and grab it there.  It only works after the "sign-in" postback, though, so
it is only useful in my specific case and wouldn't work in production.
Eventually I'll have to discover why `IAuthorizationHeaderProvider` throws
an exception for every call, but not today.

Lastly, I needed to add the razor pages and MS Identity UI, so I
didn't have to hand-craft the sign-in endpoints myself:

```
+            // razor pages are required to get signin link to work
+            services.AddRazorPages()
+                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
 
             services
                 .AddControllers()
```

3. Update the links:

```
--- a/Homepage.cs
+++ b/Homepage.cs
         </p>
         <p style='padding-left:1.6em'>
-            <a href='/AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn/AzureADB2C'>Sign-in</a> |
-            <a href='/AzureADB2C/Account/SignOut/AzureADB2C'>Sign-out</a> |
-            <a href='/AzureADB2C/Account/EditProfile/AzureADB2C'>Edit Profile</a> |
-            <a href='/AzureADB2C/Account/ResetPassword/AzureADB2C'>Reset Password</a> |
+            <a href='/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn'>Sign-in</a> |
+            <a href='/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut'>Sign-out</a> |
         </p>
         <ul>
```

I can now use the sign-in link to test the API, and copy-paste the bearer token as needed.